# Selenium with python in shared server: InitSession ERROR

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to use selenium on a shared server. Choose Chrome as browser. For that reason, I first get the sources: binary and driver. It is not possible to install otherwise or use them from the server.

For this step I went to this [url](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) and downloaded the latest version for Linux 64 (ubuntu). In this case 86299, which contains a zip called chrome-linux with the browser binary and another chromedriver_linux64 with the corresponding drive. From what I understand, I should have no compatibility issues.

However when executing I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_chrome.py", line 24, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_browser, options=opciones, port=puerto, service_log_path='/home/logs/chrome.log')
  File "/home/virtualenv/py_test/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/virtualenv/py_test/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/virtualenv/py_test/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/virtualenv/py_test/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/virtualenv/py_test/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/py_test/exec/chrome/chrome-linux/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

With this parameterization:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

path_browser = '/home/py_test/exec/chrome/chromedriver'
path_binary =  "/home/py_test/exec/chrome/chrome-linux/chrome"
puerto = 54905

opciones = Options()
opciones.binary_location = path_binary
opciones.add_argument("--headless")
opciones.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opciones.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
opciones.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
opciones.add_argument("--window-size=1024x768");
opciones.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/py_test/logs/user')
opciones.add_argument("--enable-logging");
opciones.add_argument("--single-process");
opciones.add_argument("--log-level=3");
opciones.add_argument("--start-maximized");
opciones.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
opciones.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port='+str(puerto))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_browser, options=opciones, port=puerto, service_log_path='/home/py_test/logs/chrome.log')
```

The log file on the other hand indicates:

```
[1615850954.308][INFO]: Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4448.0 (2cfe0f5060e82295490499b72a9e2891a9353b34-refs/heads/master@{#862992}) on port 54905
[1615850954.308][INFO]: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1615850955.310][INFO]: [767613b2bc316b8fedd00e8a0b17a7f9] COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1024x768", "--user-data-dir=/home/py_test/logs/user", "--enable-logging", "--single-process", "--log-level=3", "--start-maximized", "--disable-extensions", "--remote-debugging-port=54905" ],
            "binary": "/home/py_test/exec/chrome/chrome-linux/chrome",
            "extensions": [  ]
         },
         "platformName": "any"
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {

      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1024x768", "--user-data-dir=/home/py_test/logs/user", "--enable-logging", "--single-process", "--log-level=3", "--start-maximized", "--disable-extensions", "--remote-debugging-port=54905" ],
         "binary": "/home/py_test/exec/chrome/chrome-linux/chrome",
         "extensions": [  ]
      },
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[1615850955.311][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1615850955.311][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[1615850955.311][INFO]: Launching chrome: /home/py_test/exec/chrome/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --headless --log-level=3 --no-first-run --no-sandbox --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=54905 --single-process --start-maximized --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/home/py_test/logs/user --window-size=1024x768
[1615850956.341][INFO]: [767613b2bc316b8fedd00e8a0b17a7f9] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/py_test/exec/chrome/chrome-linux/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

What may be missing? Any ideas how to attack the InitSession error? How can I get selenium to run correctly? Thanks

Comment: The answer below is correct. I simply use firefox on linux. Chrome for some reason gives problems on linux.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Firefox gives error too. That is why I described here the step by step with Chrome looking for alternatives. thanks

Comment: That's strange. Never seen an error for firefox. On chrome, I gave up after many errors, this was one of them.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Firefox get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255 and log file like this: INFO Running command: "/home/py_test/browser/firefox/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "--no-sandbox" "--window-size=1920x1080" "--ignore-certificate-errors" "--ignore-ssl-errors" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileY4xTUX"
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/py_test/exec/firefox/browser/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using python library webdriver_manager:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

it allows you install driver dynamically by commands and you should not worry about its path:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

it's the solution so far, but it will make your life easier working with selenium

Comment: This time the alternative does not work, I cannot install it on the server, so the manual download. Thanks

Comment: @dblanco what error do you have? of course you can, but that way is more easier/convinient.
have you thought about using selenium grid or selenoid?